# Per process I/O accounting on AIX

Tags: performance, monitoring, aix

Is there a way of getting per process I/O statistics on AIX, i.e. to get current disk I/O rate of a process? Commands like iostat, nmon, topas etc. can't display such data. Filemon also doesn't help. Actually, what I would need is something much like iotop(1) command on Linux.

Update: it seems there is no builtin command(s) to do this. I will most probably make my own by using the [SPMI API](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/systems/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.prfusrgd/doc/prfusrgd/ch16body.htm).

Answer (score 2):

try the following command

```
ps -ef  -o ruser,pid,ppid=parent,tdiskio
```

you can play around with the -o switch to display parameters you want and hide others
and if required, you can sort the output with one of these commands using sort and awk or cut commands

Comment: For some reason TDISKIO field is "-" for all processes displayed.

Answer (score 0):

ps vx

pgin column is the number of disk I/Os resulting from references by the process to pages not loaded in core